# JSCH - Writing to remote stream while reading from remote stream

Tags: java, sftp, inputstream, jsch, outputstream

I want to get the input stream of a remote file and encrypt its byte data without downloading the file, but just by using the InputStream object returned by the following method.

1. sftpChannel.get("...");

Below is a sample of code of what i am trying to do. Here is my code:

```
InputStream is = null;
OutputStream os = null;
try {
    is = sftpChannel.get("/.../decrypted.txt");
    os = sftpChannel.put("/.../ftp_encrypted.txt", ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);

    int byteRead = is.read();
    while (byteRead != -1) {

        os.write(((byte) byteRead) << 2); //encrypt the byte in some way
        os.flush();
        byteRead = is.read();
    }
    is.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {

    if (is != null) {
        is.close();

    }

    if (os != null) {
        os.close();

    }
}
```

I thought it should have been enough but i am receiving an IOException:

> java.io.IOException: 1: End of file   at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$1.flush(ChannelSftp.java:858)

The problem seems to be related with the OutputStream object's flushing. Removing the .flush() method call does not help.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the Channel designed to handle this scenario? You may have to open two channels, one for reading, one for writing

Comment: That's a good point, so the problem can be that i cannot "stream" in both sides (in/out) because of server configuration, so the best approach is to open TWO connections, one for input and one for output. Could this be an expensive task?

Comment: No idea. Read documentation. Try.

Comment: Did you try writing just one byte? `os.write(1); os.flush(); os.close();` Does this work or you get the same exception?

Comment: @lainatnavi yes, I can read the byte but not write. I think that Andersen suggestion is the only way...

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the only way to achieve my target was to create two SFTP channels, one for input and one for output. By creating an interface and hiding these two channels I can do whatever I want without any thoughts.

Thanks for the advice, [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbj%C3%B8rn-ravn-andersen)